# z-index no superpone elementos

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un *theme* de WordPress donde, al hacer hover en la `img`, se le superpone un cuadrito verde con el texto de "ver tráiler" y aparece un recuadro `.excerpt` con posición absoluta a la izquierda. Mi problema es que `.excerpt` aparece detrás del resto de los elementos, y eso que le coloqué el `z-index` 1 a `.poster` que tiene posición relativa y `.excerpt` un `z-index` 999 que tiene posición absoluta.

El problema surge cuando se agregan varias veces ese mismo `article`. Porque los `article` tapan el `.excerpt` ¿Cómo podría hacer para que `.excerpt` aparezca sobre `.poster`?

Éste es mi código (cambiando el PHP por valores de ejemplo):

```css
.poster{
  background-color: #AFD139;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.poster strong {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}

 .ico{background: url(./img/bg.png) no-repeat;}

.poster strong .ico{
  width: 30px;
  height: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.poster:hover{background-color: #AFD139;}
.poster:hover strong{opacity:1;color:#fff;}
.poster:hover img{opacity:0.2;}
.poster:hover .excerpt{display:block;}

.poster img{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

.excerpt{
  width: 290px;
  background-color: #323232;
  padding: 10px;
  top: -11px;
  right: -341px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  display:none;
}

.excerpt i{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #323232;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.excerpt h2{
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  color:#fff!important;
  margin:0;
}

.excerpt p{
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

 .mov-medium > p{
  height:33px;
  max-height:33px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:1rem 0;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<article class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12  col-md-3  col-lg-3">
    <div class="mov-medium">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="poster">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/cats">
                <strong>
                    <i class="ico"></i>
                    VER TRAILER
                </strong>

                <div class="excerpt">
                    <i></i>
                    <h2>EL TITULO</h2>
                    El extracto
                </div>

            </div>
        </a>
        <p>EL TITULO</p>
    </div>                                                        
</article>

<article class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12  col-md-3  col-lg-3">
    <div class="mov-medium">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="poster">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/nature">
                <strong>
                    <i class="ico"></i>
                    VER TRAILER
                </strong>

                <div class="excerpt">
                    <i></i>
                    <h2>EL TITULO 2</h2>
                    El extracto 2
                </div>

            </div>
        </a>
        <p>EL TITULO 2</p>
    </div>                                                        
</article>
```

Comment: El problema no es que el `z-index` no funcione, sino dónde se coloca el extracto.  Tal y como está posicionado ahora debería verse bien y aplicarse el `z-index` sin incidentes... pero está colocado en una posición que lo deja fuera de la vista para `xs` y `sm`, sí estando visible para `md` y `lg` (puedes verlo ejecutando el ejemplo -que es tu código sin cambios, sólo hecho ejecutable-, pulsando en el botón de pantalla completa y cambiando el tamaño de la ventana). Para `md` y `lg` se ve a la derecha; para `xs` y `sm` no se ve porque queda fuera de la vista (mira como se activan los scrollers).

Comment: Claro, pero como es un efecto que sale solo en hover, y los dispositivos XS y SM son tactiles, no me preocupa que no se vean con esas resoluciones.
El problema es que lo estoy ejecutando con resolucion LG y no se ve :/

Comment: yo no veo ningun problema! con lo mencionado y comentado hasta ahora. se ve perfectamente

Comment: El problema surge cuando se agregan varias veces ese mismo `article`. Porque los article tapan el `.excerpt`

Comment: Ahora. Esa información es clave y no aparecía en la pregunta. La he editado para que se vea el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema surge porque los `z-index` de los padres afectan a los hijos; es decir, el `z-index` de un elemento limitará al de los elementos contenidos. Aunque `.excerpt` tenga un `z-index` de 999, como `.poster` tiene un `z-index` de 1, ése es el que se le va a aplicar (el 999 afectará internamente dentro de `.poster` pero no con los elementos de alrededor).

Entonces una solución rápida a tu problema sería quitar el `z-index` de poster:

```css
.poster{
  background-color: #AFD139;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  position: relative;
}

.poster strong {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}

 .ico{background: url(./img/bg.png) no-repeat;}

.poster strong .ico{
  width: 30px;
  height: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.poster:hover{background-color: #AFD139;}
.poster:hover strong{opacity:1;color:#fff;}
.poster:hover img{opacity:0.2;}
.poster:hover .excerpt{display:block;}

.poster img{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

.excerpt{
  width: 290px;
  background-color: #323232;
  padding: 10px;
  top: -11px;
  right: -341px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  display:none;
}

.excerpt i{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #323232;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.excerpt h2{
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  color:#fff!important;
  margin:0;
}

.excerpt p{
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

 .mov-medium > p{
  height:33px;
  max-height:33px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:1rem 0;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<article class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12  col-md-3  col-lg-3">
    <div class="mov-medium">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="poster">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/cats">
                <strong>
                    <i class="ico"></i>
                    VER TRAILER
                </strong>

                <div class="excerpt">
                    <i></i>
                    <h2>EL TITULO</h2>
                    El extracto
                </div>

            </div>
        </a>
        <p>EL TITULO</p>
    </div>                                                        
</article>

<article class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12  col-md-3  col-lg-3">
    <div class="mov-medium">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="poster">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/nature">
                <strong>
                    <i class="ico"></i>
                    VER TRAILER
                </strong>

                <div class="excerpt">
                    <i></i>
                    <h2>EL TITULO 2</h2>
                    El extracto 2
                </div>

            </div>
        </a>
        <p>EL TITULO 2</p>
    </div>                                                        
</article>
```

Comment: Listo, solventado. Ese era el problema. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el orden en el HTML pon primero el strong y después el img con lo q el orden ira implícito.

Comment: Se continua tapando el `.excerpt` con el `article` que tiene a la derecha.